# How to add an Express to a React app using Gulp?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, gulp

I am writing a React app that is in a good shape now. Now, I want to add a backend to access Mongodb documents and to create a REST API, as in add a layer on top of the existing project. I want Express to listen on the **same port** as my React app. I am using Gulp, starting the app using its default task.

I can't figure out a way to do that, if the `app.listen` uses the same port as the react part of it, I get `port already in use` (obviously).

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
"use strict";
var gulp = require('gulp'),
connect = require('gulp-connect'),
open = require('gulp-open'),
browserify = require('browserify'),
reactify = require('reactify'),
source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
http = require('http'),
concat = require('gulp-concat');

var config = {
port: process.env.PORT || 1991,
devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
paths: {
    html: './src/*.html',
    js: './src/**/*.jsx',
    css: './public/stylesheets/**/*.css',
    dist: './dist',
    mainJs: './src/main.jsx'
}
};

//start a local dev server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
connect.server({
    root: ['dist'],
    port: config.port,
    base: config.devBaseUrl,
    livereload: true
});
});

gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function() {
gulp.src('dist/index.html')
    .pipe(open({uri: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
gulp.src(config.paths.html)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
browserify(config.paths.mainJs)
    .transform(reactify)
    .bundle()
    .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/scripts'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
gulp.src(config.paths.css)
    .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
    .pipe(eslint({configFile: 'eslint.config.json'}))
    .pipe(eslint.format());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
console.log('Files have been changed... Reloading...');
gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
gulp.watch(config.paths.css, ['css']);
gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'js', 'css','lint', 'open', 'watch']);
```

I tried to combine a generated express app, so my folder looked like this:
[image: Folder structure after adding Express parts]

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean when you say "I want to add a backend, Express." What is your goal of the backend. It looks to me like you already have gulp tasks that spin up a simple server and live reload the files on change. What do you want the express server to do?

Comment: I want to add a REST API and manage mongodb documents.
Yeah, the app is in a good shape, but it's only a front end app. The point is that I want it to be a full-stack app.

Comment: Okay. What are you planning on hosting this on? AWS? A dedicated server/droplet on Digital Oceaen? Azure?

Comment: Using Heroku and Github.

Comment: You can't have 2 apps running on the same port, as you've discovered :) Don't think of it as "adding Express to the React app." Express will be the server - that's the base layer. It will respond to API requests, but it will _also_ serve your React app as a static asset. Express will replace your 'connect' dev server, and do double-duty.

Comment: Correct. Just figured that out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out a way to do it. As I said in the question (but with more details): combining a the current React app with an Express Generated app was the right approach. So what I did was basically:

1. Add the bin, views & routes folder and the app.js file to the React project folder
2. Add this line in `app.js` to serve the destination JS file generated for the React components:
   `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));`
3. Edit the connect task to delete the port configuration. It will figure it out later when starting the server. Add one more task in the gulpfile.js: 
   `gulp.task('dev', ['html', 'js', 'css','lint', 'connect', 'watch']);`
4. In package.json, edit the start script calling the new gulp task: `gulp dev && node ./bin/www`
5. Copy and paste the dependencies from the Express App package.json file to the new React project one's.
6. Delete the node_modules folder and rerun `npm install`
7. run `npm start` to start the full stack app.

Hope this could help anyone.

Comment: Extra info: used [Express Generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) to generate the ExpressApp. && don't forget to adjust your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the extra information you gave in the comments, I would recommend do one of two options:

- Host the API separately. On a separate port and maybe even in a separate repository. Separation of concerns.

or

- Adjust your gulp tasks to start an express server and serve your static content out of the express app. Then you can set up your api routes to return json and request the json from your static content (html) via AJAX requests, or whatever.

Either way, you can use [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to live reload your API &/or your static content server.

Hope that helps. It's easy to generate an express app using the [express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. However, I know I have those options but that do not solve my problem. The most important piece was adding Express on the same port.

Comment: It does answer your question. You either host it on a different port, or you stop hosting your static content through browserify and instead host it through express on the same port as your api (which would be in the same project). You cannot host two apps on the same port. Also, I didn't downvote you, so please don't downvote me. :)

Comment: What you really need is to serve your react app via your express app. OR you serve your express app on a different port.